# SQL Nested CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the following query segment in a Sales Analysis cube. I'm not deeply familiar with SQL.

The first CASE statement works as it should - returns a negative when OINV.Canceled = 'Y'.

```
CASE OINV.Canceled WHEN 'Y' THEN - INV1.LineTotal 
ELSE INV1.LineTotal END AS LineTotal, 
CASE INV1.StockSum WHEN 0 THEN INV1.LineTotal 
ELSE INV1.StockSum END AS SaleValue, INV1.GrssProfit
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for the second CASE statement to also return a negative value (SaleValue) when OINV.Canceled = 'Y'. I think I need to nest a CASE statement here but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [two formats of Case Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). Simple case and Searched case.
You can do it with a Searched case expression.

```
CASE WHEN  OINV.Canceled = 'Y' THEN -INV1.StockSum 
     WHEN  INV1.StockSum = 0 THEN INV1.LineTotal
     ELSE  INV1.StockSum 
END AS SaleValue
```

Or it could be (depending on your requirement)

```
CASE WHEN  OINV.Canceled = 'Y' AND INV1.StockSum = 0 THEN -INV1.LineTotal
     WHEN  OINV.Canceled = 'Y' AND INV1.StockSum <> 0 THEN -INV1.StockSum 
     ELSE  INV1.StockSum 
END AS SaleValue
```

Or a nested case. Here you have to repeat sub case expression for different values of `OINV.Canceled`.

```
 CASE OINV.Canceled WHEN 'Y' THEN
                    -1 * CASE INV1.StockSum WHEN 0 THEN INV1.LineTotal 
                         ELSE INV1.StockSum END
                    ELSE 
                         CASE INV1.StockSum WHEN 0 THEN INV1.LineTotal 
                         ELSE INV1.StockSum END
 END AS SaleValue
```

Comment: I think you omitted **AND**, e.g. `OINV.Canceled = 'Y' AND INV1.StockSum = 0`.

Comment: Thank you, this was pretty much it. I had to add a third condition to the CASE statement but that was it: WHEN OINV.Canceled = 'N' AND              INV1.StockSum = 0 THEN INV1.LineTotal

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CASE 
  When OINV.Canceled = 'Y' THEN  INV1.LineTotal *(-1)
  ELSE INV1.LineTotal 
END AS LineTotal, 
CASE 
  When INV1.StockSum = 0 THEN INV1.LineTotal 
  ELSE INV1.StockSum 
END AS SaleValue, 
INV1.GrssProfit
```